# Records deduplication(linkage) algorithms

Tags: algorithm, graph, duplicates, cluster-analysis, record-linkage

I have a standart record deduplication task:
I have alot records with some text ( or some other ) fields , some of them corresponding to the same entity. Merging of such records is the goal of the task.

There is some widely used and simple statistical approachs for this kind of tasks
like "[Probabilistic Record Linkage](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/media-library/sites/cmm/migrated/documents/problinkage.pdf)". Some of them are more precise and more complicated but exploit the same ideas like https://github.com/datamade/dedupe:
They try to weight somehow each field as a measure of similarity and then linear composition of weighted differences as measure of the whole record similarity.

But for some tasks I have alot of unknown fields, but the amount of similar fields is rather large like :

```
record1 : propA = A ; propB = unknown ; propC = unknown ;  ....
record2 : propA = A ; propB = B ; propC = unknown ; ....
record3 : propA = unkown ; propB = B ; propC = D ; ....

record4 : propA = A2 ; propB = unknown ; propC = unknown ;  ....
record5 : propA = A2 ; propB = B2 ; propC = unknown ; ....
record6 : propA = X2 ; propB = B2 ; propC = D2 ; ....
```

in this case record1 can be linked with record3 via record2 much more likely as 
record4 with record6.

This means that i need some similar as graph clustering but with alot of skips and a really huge amount of nodes and edges. 
I don't need a precise solution but something better as classical statistical deduplikation must exist.

Answer (score 1):

Dedupe handles missing data and does do graph clustering.  There are other paradigms for record linkage, but your data does not seem to demand it.

If you want to investigate at newer paradigms, look at the work of Beka Steorts or Michael Wick.